# Cognos Analytics Rest Api/Api-docs 404 not found issue

Tags: http-status-code-404, rest, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I was using Cognos SDK for development purpose, now I am planning to shift to Cognos analytics server rest API.

Following [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.1.0?topic=apis-rest-api), I tried to frame the URL as `http://<cognos_analytics_server:port>/api/api-docs`, but I ended in 404 not found.

But when I use `/bi/api/api-docs` (i.e. `http://<cognos_analytics_server:port>/bi/api/api-docs`), it's working but I don't find many apis in that swagger.

Can anyone assist me, why is it showing 404? Do I need to do any additional setup for rest API swagger to work?

Also attached how my screen looks when I try to access this request `http://<cognos_analytics_server:port>/api/api-docs`

[image: 404errorscreenshot]

Comment: When you say "when I use /bi/api/api-docs (i.e. http://<cognos_analytics_server:port>/bi/api/api-docs), it's working but I don't find many apis in that swagger," do you see fewer than the APIs shown on the [REST API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.1.0?topic=api-rest-reference)?  I think the URL you are using is correct and the REST API is simply much more limited at the moment than the SOAP SDK.  It is possible that you are simply seeing what is currently available.